# Atlassian Sourcetree - capture change

Tags: c#, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

Is there any way to detect change in sourcetree like branch change(active branch) or active Repository etc? I was checking log file but it does not show / indicate active branch name.

Please advise me if it is possible so I can integrate one feature with my C# application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Changes to the repo (active branch etc) should be visible by inspecting the .git folder in the root of the repo:

http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/03/23/whats-inside-your-git-directory.html

You can subscribe to changes on the filesystem to be notified when it changes:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

There are projects to interact directly with git from c#, such as:

https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/

and using git commands like git-ls-files should give you detailed information about whats changed:

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-files.html